# Ubuntu server on HP workstation

Tags: server, 17.04

I have HP workstation Z440 : Xeon W3520 and I want to make on it Ubuntu server.
Is it compatible? 
thank you.

Comment: I don't think 'minimal system requirements' describes this situation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably. The CPU is not that useful to know - all modern CPU's work just fine with whatever you throw at them. For a server the following is important:

- Supported disk controller.
- Supported network cards.
- Supported chip set.

HP has an affinity for Broadcom NIC's. I'm not terribly fond of BCM, but they tend to work just fine. Anyway, a gigabit Intel NIC costs you ~20-30$, and will work flawlessly. So this is not much of a worry in my opinion.

The real kicker here is the disk controller. [HP lists](http://store.hp.com/us/en/mdp/business-solutions/z440-workstation-244024--1#!&Tab=features) the following options:

- Integrated SATA 6.0 Gb/s;
- LSI MegaRAID® 9270-8i SAS 6.0 Gb/s ROC RAID Card and iBBU09 Battery Backup Unit (optional);  LSI 9217-4i4e
- 8-port SAS 6.0 Gb/s RAID (optional);
- Factory integrated RAID available for SATA/SAS drives (RAID 0, 0 Data, 1, and 10);
- Factory integrated RAID available for PCIe SSDs (RAID 0 Data)

The Integrated SATA is probably a standard Intel chipset SATA port, and will probably work just fine, and can be used with Linux Software raid for multiple drives.

The Megaraid 9270 [appears to be fairly well supported as well](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man4/mrsas.4freebsd.html).

Regarding the three last options, they are not specific, and may or may not be fake-raid / software raid. In this case - use the builtin Intel SATA ports and Linux software raid if you desire redundancy options.

So overall: Yes, it will probably run Linux. The easiest way to figure out how well is probably to install Ubuntu. Note what's not working properly, and find a solution for the problems that arise.